# Grails 2.3.1 in GGTS(Eclipse): Out of memory error when using run-script

Tags: eclipse, grails, run-script

I am executing a groovy script with run-script and running out of memory. I have found instructions for configuring ones GRAILS_OPTS on the command line, however I am not on the command line. How do I make sure that the grails command prompt in GGTS(Eclipse) is configured to provide enough memory for a script?

Just to be clear - this is a problem with run-script from the groovy command prompt inside The GGTS 3.4.0 release (Eclipse).

Comment: `Run as > Run configurations`

Comment: That gets me to the "| Error Error loading plugin manager: TomcatGrailsPlugin (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)" bug. The way I've found to get around that bug is to execute 'grails compile' and then 'grails run-script <myscript>', but this only works through the Grails command prompt, not through Run As.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the **JAVA_OPTS** system variable instead of the specific GRAILS_OPTS variable. It seems to work for me.
e.g

**JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"**

For reference from grails docs  - http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html, search for JAVA_OPTS. Depending on what OS you are on the syntax may be different.

Comment: The problem is actually from inside Eclipse though.